# Align 2 TextViews one under other but centered to their relative parent

Tags: android, layout, alignment

I'm trying to center a TextView under another one (it's centering), but I'm getting this

[image]

The 2 items are not aligned correctly (as I'd want)

I'm looking for something like this:

[image]

You can see both items centered, not just the bigger one

my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/r1"
android:clickable="true"
android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
>
   <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/download"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/descricao"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:text="Texto de baixo"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/titulo"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/status" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titulo"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Text Title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/status" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT**

Thanks Der Golem, your answer made the trick, but I got another problem, the text when it gets more than one line, is there a way not to hide it behind the below text, and align it again?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are `nearly there`: Observe the drawing.

Be the red line a `generic View` (let's give it an id of `vwDummy`), aligned to the center of the row (`android:layout_centerInParent="true"`).

Let its dimensions be **0dp** and **0dp**.

Then Just put the title **above** it (`android:layout_above="@id/vwDummy"`).
And put the lower text **below** it (`android:layout_below="@id/vwDummy"`).

Comment: Hi, thank you it worked, but i got another problem, see my edit

Comment: To make your text go on more lines, simply use `android:inputType="textMultiLine"` in your TextView.

Comment: Der thats not the problem, that multiline i know, but the second line if overlayed by the second textview

Comment: not solved the second problem, but the question you really solved, thank you, and because your help i solved the second, i just made the dummy item         android:padding="8dp" (and this made everything like i want) thank u

Answer (score 1):

Just change the layout_height of the parent layout to wrap_content from "?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/r1"
android:clickable="true"
android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
<ImageButton

        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/download"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/descricao"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:text="Texto de baixo"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/titulo"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/status" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titulo"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Text Title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/status" />

</RelativeLayout>
```